# QML: Property Animation, the X Coordinate always back to old position [Editted]

Tags: qt, animation, position, qml, qt-quick

I made an animation that the 4 rectangle is change the x position, one to another.
This is the screen shot of the default position:

I assume that:
- picture1 = **A**
- picture2 = **B**
- picture3 = **C**
- picture4 = **D**

The position is:

```
A      B

C      D
```

And After the animation is occurred, then the position change to be like this:

```
B      A

D      C
```

After animation (id:anim1) occurred,  then strange condition appeared. suddenly both left picture (B & D) move to right (back to earlier position)

```
       BA

       DC
```

Why it couuld be like this?

here is my animation code. (my animation call after transition being run)

```
Transition {
        from: ""
        to: "StartGame"
        reversible: false
        SequentialAnimation{
            PropertyAnimation{
                properties: "width"
                duration: 300
            }
            PropertyAnimation{
                properties: "x"
                duration: 500
            }
            PauseAnimation { duration: 200 }
            ParallelAnimation{
                PropertyAnimation{target: rot1; property: "angle"; from:0; to: 180; duration: 1000}
                PropertyAnimation{target: rot2; property: "angle"; from:0; to: 180; duration: 1000}
                PropertyAnimation{target: rot3; property: "angle"; from:0; to: 180; duration: 1000}
                PropertyAnimation{target: rot4; property: "angle"; from:0; to: 180; duration: 1000}
            }

            PauseAnimation { duration: 1000 }

            ScriptAction{
                script: anim1.start();
            }
    }
```

and here is the anim1:

```
ParallelAnimation{
    id: anim1
    PropertyAnimation{
        target: card1
        property: "x"
        to: 550
        duration: 700
    }
    PropertyAnimation{
        target: card3
        properties: "x"
        to: 550
        duration: 700
    }
    PropertyAnimation{
        target: card2
        properties: "x"
        to: 100
        duration: 700
    }
    PropertyAnimation{
        target: card4
        properties: "x"
        to: 100
        duration: 700
    }
}
```

I need to solve this problem as soon as possible.
thx for your attention

Here is the full code:

```
// import QtQuick 1.0 // to target S60 5th Edition or Maemo 5
import QtQuick 1.1
import "../../javascript/Functions.js" as Script

Rectangle {
    id: mainScreen
    width: 800
    height: 600
    property variant datas : [0,0,0,0]

    /*Main Menu*/
    Rectangle{
        id: startGame
        width: parent.width/2
        height: parent.height
        anchors.left: parent.left
        color: "#08FC39"
        Text{
            id: txtStartGame
            text: "Start Game"
            anchors{
                horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }
            color: "White"
            font{bold: true; family: "Segoe UI Bold"; pointSize: 15}
        }
        MouseArea{
            id: maStartGame
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                Script.randomPict();
                Script.randomAnimation();
                mainScreen.state="StartGame"
            }
        }
    }
    Rectangle{
        id: highScore
        width: parent.width/2
        height: parent.height
        anchors.right: parent.right
        color: "#0851FC"
        Text{
            id: txtHighScore
            text: "High Score"
            anchors{
                horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }
            color: "white"
            font{bold: true; family: "Segoe UI Bold"; pointSize: 15}
        }
        MouseArea{
            id: maHighScore
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: mainScreen.state="HighScore"
        }
    }
    /*------------------------------*/

    /*StartGame*/
    Text{
        id: startGameTitle
        visible: false
        anchors{
            top: mainScreen.top
            topMargin: 20
            horizontalCenter: mainScreen.horizontalCenter
        }
        text: "Choose This Picture"
        color: "white"
        font{bold:true; family: "Segoe UI Bold"; pointSize: 20}
    }

    Flipable{
        id:card1
        width: 150
        height: width
        visible: false
        x:-width
        y:100
        transform: Rotation {
            id: rot1
            origin.x: card1.width/2
            origin.y: 0
            axis.x: 0; axis.y: 1; axis.z: 0;
            angle: 0
            onAngleChanged: img1.source = "../../images/models/"+Script.getPict(0)+".jpg";
            Behavior on angle {PropertyAnimation{}}
        }
        front:
            Rectangle {
                color: "#FAFF70"
                width: 150
                height: width
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    onClicked: {
                        //img1.source =  "../../images/models/"+Script.getPict(0)+".jpg"
                        Script.showBack(rot1);
                    }
                }
        }

        back:
            Image {
                id: img1
                width: 150
                height: width
                property variant no: Script.getPict(0);
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    onClicked:
                    {
                        Script.showFront(rot1);
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    Flipable{
        id:card2
        width: 150
        height: width
        visible: false
        x: mainScreen.width
        y: 100
        transform: Rotation {
            id: rot2
            origin.x: card2.width/2
            origin.y: 0
            axis.x: 0; axis.y: 1; axis.z: 0;
            angle: 0
            onAngleChanged: img2.source = "../../images/models/"+Script.getPict(1)+".jpg";
            Behavior on angle {PropertyAnimation{}}
        }
        front:
            Rectangle {
                color: "#FAFF70"
                width: 150
                height: width
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    onClicked: {
                        //img2.source =  "../../images/models/"+Script.getPict(1)+".jpg"
                        Script.showBack(rot2);
                    }
                }
        }

        back:
            Image {
                id: img2
                width: 150
                height: width
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    onClicked:
                    {
                        Script.showFront(rot2);
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    Flipable{
        id:card3
        width: 150
        height: width
        visible: false
        x: -width
        y: mainScreen.height - width - 50
        transform: Rotation {
            id: rot3
            origin.x: card3.width/2
            origin.y: 0
            axis.x: 0; axis.y: 1; axis.z: 0;
            angle: 0
            onAngleChanged: img3.source = "../../images/models/"+Script.getPict(2)+".jpg";
            Behavior on angle {PropertyAnimation{}}
        }
        front:
            Rectangle {
                color: "#FAFF70"
                width: 150
                height: width
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    onClicked: {
                        //img3.source =  "../../images/models/"+Script.getPict(2)+".jpg"
                        Script.showBack(rot3);
                    }
                }
        }

        back:
            Image {
                id: img3
                width: 150
                height: width
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    onClicked:
                    {
                        Script.showFront(rot3);
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    Flipable{
        id:card4
        width: 150
        height: width
        visible: false
        x: mainScreen.width
        y: mainScreen.height - width - 50
        transform: Rotation {
            id: rot4
            origin.x: card4.width/2
            origin.y: 0
            axis.x: 0; axis.y: 1; axis.z: 0;
            angle: 0
            onAngleChanged: img4.source = "../../images/models/"+Script.getPict(3)+".jpg";
            Behavior on angle {PropertyAnimation{}}
        }
        front:
            Rectangle {
                color: "#FAFF70"
                width: 150
                height: width
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    onClicked: {
                        //img4.source =  "../../images/models/"+Script.getPict(3)+".jpg"
                        Script.showBack(rot4);
                    }
                }
        }

        back:
            Image {
                id: img4
                width: 150
                height: width
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    onClicked:
                    {
                        Script.showFront(rot4);
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    /*------------------------------*/
    states:[
        State{
            name: "MainMenu"
            PropertyChanges{
                target: startGame
                width: mainScreen.width/2
            }
            PropertyChanges{
                target: highScore
                width: mainScreen.width/2
            }
        },
        State{
            name: "StartGame"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: startGame
                width: mainScreen.width
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: highScore
                width: 0
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: txtStartGame
                visible: false
            }
            PropertyChanges{
                target: txtHighScore
                visible: false
            }
            PropertyChanges{
                target: maStartGame
                enabled: false
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: card1
                visible: true
                x: 100
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: card2
                visible: true
                x: mainScreen.width - card2.width - 100
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: card3
                visible: true
                x: 100
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: card4
                visible: true
                x: mainScreen.width - card4.width - 100
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: startGameTitle
                visible: true
            }
        },
        State{
            name: "HighScore"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: startGame
                width: 0
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: highScore
                width: mainScreen.width
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: txtStartGame
                visible: false
            }
            PropertyChanges{
                target: txtHighScore
                visible: false
            }
            PropertyChanges{
                target: maHighScore
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    ]

    transitions:[
        Transition {
            from: ""
            to: "StartGame"
            reversible: false
            SequentialAnimation{
                PropertyAnimation{
                    properties: "width"
                    duration: 300
                }
                PropertyAnimation{
                    properties: "x"
                    duration: 500
                }
                PauseAnimation { duration: 200 }
                ParallelAnimation{
                    PropertyAnimation{target: rot1; property: "angle"; from:0; to: 180; duration: 1000}
                    PropertyAnimation{target: rot2; property: "angle"; from:0; to: 180; duration: 1000}
                    PropertyAnimation{target: rot3; property: "angle"; from:0; to: 180; duration: 1000}
                    PropertyAnimation{target: rot4; property: "angle"; from:0; to: 180; duration: 1000}
                }

                PauseAnimation { duration: 1000 }

                ScriptAction{
                    script: anim1.start();
                }
            }
        },
        Transition {
            from: ""
            to: "HighScore"
            PropertyAnimation{
                properties: "width"
                duration: 300
            }
        }
    ]
    ParallelAnimation{
        id: anim1
        PropertyAnimation{
            target: card1
            property: "x"
            to: 550
            duration: 700
        }
        PropertyAnimation{
            target: card3
            properties: "x"
            to: 550
            duration: 700
        }
        PropertyAnimation{
            target: card2
            properties: "x"
            to: 100
            duration: 700
        }
        PropertyAnimation{
            target: card4
            properties: "x"
            to: 100
            duration: 700
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you put the code of anim1 directly in the Transition? Also we need a minimum compilable code sample to figure out the problem, because it looks like the problem may come from somewhere else in your code

Comment: i had already post the new code. I have tried to put anim1 in Transition, but it doesn't work to.. I use ScriptAction because i want to add extra logic using Javascript in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    State{
        name: "StartGame"
        PropertyChanges {
            target: startGame
            width: mainScreen.width
        }
        PropertyChanges {
            target: highScore
            width: 0
        }
        PropertyChanges {
            target: txtStartGame
            visible: false
        }
        PropertyChanges{
            target: txtHighScore
            visible: false
        }
        PropertyChanges{
            target: maStartGame
            enabled: false
        }
        PropertyChanges {
            target: card1
            visible: true
            x: 100
        }
        PropertyChanges {
            target: card2
            visible: true
            x: mainScreen.width - card2.width - 100
        }
        PropertyChanges {
            target: card3
            visible: true
            x: 100
        }
        PropertyChanges {
            target: card4
            visible: true
            x: mainScreen.width - card4.width - 100
        }
        PropertyChanges {
            target: startGameTitle
            visible: true
        }
    },
```

In your "startgame" state you reset the x of all the cards... change 'x: 100' to 'x: 500' for card1, and so on.

Also next time when providing a code try to trim it down to the essentials showing the problem and that can still work as a stand-alone, not the whole thing.

Comment: @MuhammadZullidar Please accept this answer if you consider it resolving